# Django many to many filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I have many to many field in user model where one user can have multiple roles for example admin, patient, doctor and others. now I want to query data to get users with admin and all other roles and not doctor and patient role. I am using this

```
User.objects.exclude(roles__code_name__in=['pt', 'doc'])
```

now my one user signs up as patient too so he has admin and patient role both now i am unable to get him by using above query. so concluding... if user has two roles if one of it is patient and he has any other role too i want to get him too. what should i do? Thanks in advance

UPDATE

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
email                   = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
first_name              = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name               = models.CharField(max_length=30)
cnic                    = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
mobile                  = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
dob                     = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
profile_image           = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_path, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image_path)
next_of_kin_name        = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
next_of_kin_mobile      = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
is_delete               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
status                  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
contact                 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
hospital                = models.ForeignKey('Hospital', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
roles                   = models.ManyToManyField('Role', related_name='users')
is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
balance                 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
gender                  = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=gender_choices, default=gender_choices[0][0])
phone_verified          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
created_by              = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='+', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
updated_at              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
updated_by              = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='+', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my model it has roles as many to many field. i have multiple roles like doctor, patient, admin and many others custom created roles with custom permissions. I have a view where i want to get data of users that are not patients or doctors. everything was working fine until one of my admin user decides to sign up as patient so he has now both patient and admin role and now i am unable to get him by using above mentioned query

Comment: Can you please share your models and add your desired output?

Comment: @SmitParmar hi i have updated question please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka. This solution is working fine for me idk if it's the ideal approach bit is working at the moment. Thanks @all

```
User.objects.annotate(num_roles=Count('roles')).exclude(Q(id=self.request.user.id) | Q(is_delete=True) | Q(roles__code_name__in=['pt', 'doc', 'su']) & Q(num_roles=1)).order_by('-id')
```